# Excluding single row based on contents of two columns in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I hope you can help me. I have the query below that runs successfully and returns perhaps a 100 or so rows.

```
SELECT DOMAIN_NAME AS "Domain", PROJECT_NAME AS "Project", MAX(END_TIME) AS "Last Accessed"
FROM DB.td.SESSIONS_HISTORY
WHERE SESSIONS_HISTORY.USER_NAME NOT IN ('UserA', 'UserB', 'UserC')
GROUP BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
ORDER BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
```

However, within the returned dataset are two rows that contain the same Project Name, i.e.

```
Domain      Project  Last Accessed
PASSENGERS  Alpha    2015-02-25 10:56:36
AIRPORTS    Alpha    2015-01-09 11:11:50
```

I want to explicitly exlude the AIRPORTS Alpha row from the dataset. Having read other posts I have tried the query below (and variations thereof), but I then have 0 rows returned, which is not the desired results.

```
SELECT DOMAIN_NAME AS "Domain", PROJECT_NAME AS "Project", MAX(END_TIME) AS "Last Accessed"
FROM DB.td.SESSIONS_HISTORY
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM DB.td.SESSIONS_HISTORY
    WHERE SESSIONS_HISTORY.DOMAIN_NAME = 'AIRPORTS' AND SESSIONS_HISTORY.PROJECT_NAME = 'Alpha'
    )
AND SESSIONS_HISTORY.USER_NAME NOT IN ('UserA', 'UserB', 'UserC')
GROUP BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
ORDER BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
```

How can I amend my query to exclude the AIRPORTS Alpha row? Please note, I do not need a solution that excludes based on the date field, just the combination of the DOMAIN_NAME and PROJECT_NAME. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean something like "WHERE NOT (DOMAIN_NAME = 'AIRPORTS' AND PROJECT_NAME = 'Alpha')"?

Comment: Hello. Thank @Arvo that is the solution! I'm not sure how to mark it as that though as you added it as a comment! Thanks again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There were two answers provided which were effective for me.

Thank you to @Arvo for:

```
SELECT DOMAIN_NAME AS "Domain", PROJECT_NAME AS "Project", MAX(END_TIME) AS "Last Accessed"
FROM DB.td.SESSIONS_HISTORY
WHERE SESSIONS_HISTORY.USER_NAME NOT IN ('UserA', 'UserB', 'UserC')
AND NOT (DOMAIN_NAME = 'AIRPORTS' AND PROJECT_NAME = 'Alpha')
GROUP BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
ORDER BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
```

And thank you to @ASh for the equally effective:

```
SELECT DOMAIN_NAME AS "Domain", PROJECT_NAME AS "Project", MAX(END_TIME) AS "Last Accessed"
FROM DB.td.SESSIONS_HISTORY
WHERE SESSIONS_HISTORY.USER_NAME NOT IN ('UserA', 'UserB', 'UserC')
AND (DOMAIN_NAME <> 'AIRPORTS' or PROJECT_NAME <> 'Alpha')
GROUP BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
ORDER BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DOMAIN_NAME AS "Domain", PROJECT_NAME AS "Project", MAX(END_TIME) AS "Last Accessed"
FROM DB.td.SESSIONS_HISTORY
WHERE SESSIONS_HISTORY.USER_NAME NOT IN ('UserA', 'UserB', 'UserC')

and (DOMAIN_NAME <> 'AIRPORTS' or PROJECT_NAME <> 'Alpha')

GROUP BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
ORDER BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
```

Comment: @SirChuffsalot, i modified the query

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your response @ASh. Unfortunately this will not work for me as there are other AIRPORT entries that must be included in the dataset.  I need to just exclude the specific combination of DOMAIN_NAME and PROJECT_NAME of AIRPORTS and Alpha.

Comment: @SirChuffsalot, the query should EXCLUDE only rows with DOMAIN_NAME = 'AIRPORTS' and PROJECT_NAME = 'Alpha'. am i missing something in your comment? why exactly this doen't work ?

Comment: Hello @ASh. Actually it does work now. When you editted the answer from: `and DOMAIN_NAME <> 'AIRPORTS'` to `and (DOMAIN_NAME <> 'AIRPORTS' or PROJECT_NAME <> 'Alpha')` it then worked and excluded the unrequired row. Someone else also suggested `"WHERE NOT (DOMAIN_NAME = 'AIRPORTS' AND PROJECT_NAME = 'Alpha')` which was just as effective but less brain power to interpret the double <> :o) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Select the rows where the end_time = max(end_time) for same DOMAIN_NAME/PROJECT_NAME combination:

```
SELECT DOMAIN_NAME AS "Domain",
       PROJECT_NAME AS "Project",
       END_TIME AS "Last Accessed"
FROM DB.td.SESSIONS_HISTORY t1
WHERE USER_NAME NOT IN ('UserA', 'UserB', 'UserC')
AND END_TIME = (SELECT MAX(END_TIME)
                FROM DB.td.SESSIONS_HISTORY t2
                WHERE USER_NAME NOT IN ('UserA', 'UserB', 'UserC')
                  AND t1.DOMAIN_NAME = t2.DOMAIN_NAME
                  AND t1.PROJECT_NAME = t2.PROJECT_NAME)
ORDER BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your response @jarlh. Unfortunately this will not work for me as I do not need a solution that excludes based on the date field, just the specific combination of the DOMAIN_NAME and PROJECT_NAME of AIRPORTS and Alpha.

Comment: And I thought I wrote a general query, resolving all duplicates... Well, I guess some of the other answers will do fine.

Comment: Hello @jarlh. I didn't need to remove duplicates. I just needed to exclude on specific combination (1 row) of data.  It was a duplicate of any other row, it just contained the same ProjectName.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DOMAIN_NAME AS "Domain", PROJECT_NAME AS "Project", MAX(END_TIME) AS "Last Accessed"
FROM DB.td.SESSIONS_HISTORY
WHERE SESSIONS_HISTORY.USER_NAME NOT IN ('UserA', 'UserB', 'UserC')
AND DOMAIN_NAME <> 'AIRPORTS'
AND PROJECT_NAME <> 'Alpha'
GROUP BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
ORDER BY DOMAIN_NAME, PROJECT_NAME
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your response @mcl. Unfortunately this will not work for me as there are other AIRPORT DOMAIN_NAME entries and other Alpha PROJECT_NAME entries that must be included in the dataset. I need to just exclude the specific combination DOMAIN_NAME and PROJECT_NAME of AIRPORTS and Alpha.